# How send such data from site to server?

Tags: javascript, python, html, request

I have a code:

```
<form method="POST">
    <div name='all_links'>
        <a href="#" name='link>click</a>
    </div>
</form>
```

`<a>` tags creates dynamic, and I need to add all of them to database at server
I've tried use:

`request.form['all_links']` and `request.form['link']`, but it's not working
Python Flask server

Comment: On your `a` link, should it be `<a href="#" name="link">click</a>`? You have missed a quote mark :)

Comment: I can't understand 
Which a quote mark?

Comment: You should really go and find yourself a tutorial that explains the absolute basics of working with forms in HTML. Forms send the data contained in actual form input elements (input, textarea, select) - and not anything contained in other elements such as `div` or `a`.

Comment: @XymisTwice the one on the `name` attribute. So that means that `name='link` becomes `name='link'`, with a quote mark at the end

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/name) the name attribute can only be applied to a few elements

> name gets or sets the name property of an element in the DOM. It only applies to the following elements: `<a>, <applet>, <button>, <form>, <frame>, <iframe>, <img>, <input>, <map>, <meta>, <object>, <param>, <select>, and <textarea>`.

so div elements can't have a name attribute, you should update your html to one of the above elements

Answer (score 0):

name gets or sets the name property of an element in the DOM. It only applies to to some elements in html

so div elements can't have a name attribute, you should update your html to one of the above elements

Answer (score 0):

According to the Docs the name attribute can only be applied to a few elements
name gets or sets the name property of an element in the DOM. It only applies to the following elements: `<a>`, `<applet>`, `<button>`, `<form>`, `<frame>`, `<iframe>`, `<img>`, `<input>`, `<map>`, `<meta>`, `<object>`, `<param>`, `<select>`, and `<textarea>`.

Comment: <a>, <applet>, <button>, <form>, <frame>, <iframe>, <img>, <input>, <map>, <meta>, <object>, <param>, <select>, and <textarea>

Comment: If you want to use code, like DOM-Elements you can escape them in the text using Backticks: `